# Getting inconsistent "invalid literal for int()" error

Tags: python-2.7

Although this is a super common error, I haven't found a solution for this particular issue.

I have a script with a line that reads

```
line = int(ser.readline())
```

Sometimes (not everytime!) when I run this script is get this error:

```
Traceback(most recent call last):
  File "./project.py", line 28, in <module>
  line = int(ser.readline())
  ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:' '
```

When this happens, I can simply restart the script, and it works fine.

What's going on here? Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

Here's the full script, for reference. The offending code is on line 28.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import time
import serial
import subprocess

# -------------function for videos-------------

def play_vid_nonblocking(num):
    return subprocess.Popen(["xterm", "-fullscreen", "-e", "omxplayer", "-o", "hdmi", "-r", "/home/pi/Ligia/{:02d}.mp4".format(num)])

# -------------sensor setup-------------

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)

# -----------------------------------------

num_videos = 10

i = 1

p = None

time.sleep(60)
while True:
        line = int(ser.readline())
        print line
        if line < 750:
                if p is None or p.poll() is not None:
                        p = play_vid_nonblocking(i)
                        time.sleep(60)
                        i = i + 1
                        if i > num_videos:
                                i = 0
                        else:
                                pass
                else:
                        pass
        else:
                pass

ser.close()
```

Comment: Evidently you're sometimes reading in whitespace, which cannot be made an integer. What do you think *should* happen in that case? Could you just [handle the error](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) and keep going?

Comment: Unrelated: `else: pass` does nothing but make your code look mad. You can omit the `else` clause entirely.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes, this was the issue. Fixed by adding a "Try" statement. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

@jonrsharpe above suggested the script was sometimes reading whitespace. This was fixed by adding a "Try" statement:

```
try:
    line = int(line)
```